# CakePHP 1.3: Alaxos ACL Plugin not recognizing Pages Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, acl

I have been developing with CakePHP and the Alaxos ACL plugin has helped in tremendously.

However, I am facing one issue I am not sure how to fix it?

I added a plugin named 'pages', but I cannot get ACL to see it so it is added to the list of allowed/denied actions.

If I access the plugin thru domain.com/pages/pages I get the following error

```
DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.
```

When I check thru the ACL plugin display, there is no reference to the pages controller and if I run the ACL build function, it simply says that there is nothing to add.

Is it because this controller is named pages and there is already a pages controller within Cake?

If it is how do I fix it? Is my only option, at this time, adding this manually to the Db? Should I go thru this plugin and rename pages to something else? or is there anything else I should be doing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I see two things here. First like you suspect, having two classes in your application that share the same name is a bad idea. It will likely give you some problems in one way or another, with the wrong class being instantiated or whatever. As far as Cake does not use namespaces, this is not recommended.

Then, even if you change this name, there will be another problem if the controller you want to manage with ACL is the 'default' controller (a controller that has the same name as the plugin). There was an issue with the ACO nodes retrieval when the path contains twice the same name, which is the case for plugins default controllers.

```
controllers/Pages/Pages/index
```

So I decided to just skip the plugins default controllers from the controllers supported by the ACL plugin.

If you are the author of this plugin, you could rename it (because PagesController exists already), and move the actions in some other controller than the default controller.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I went thru this plugin and changed everything so as to make it accessible thru `Paginas.Paginas`. However, I still cant get the ACL Plugin to detect it. If I add `$this->Auth->allow('*')` to the `beforeFilter()` function on this controller, then I am able to access this plugin and process everything as designed. However, the minute I comment that out, I go back to the same ARO/ACO error. The only thing I can think of right now is to manually enter information for this and all its non-public actions in the ACO/ARO tables. Let me know if you have anymore suggestions...

Comment: I will also update this post if I am able to make this work by manually entering the data into Db. I am just not sure why the Alaxos ACL plugin cannot detect this and add it.

Comment: As I told you, if you use a default controller (controller with the same name as the plugin) the Acl plugin does not see it. I had to do it like this, because I used to think there was a bug in the core AclNode class. But actually I have realized a few days ago that the problem was on my side (http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/1739-case-insensitive-acos-table-can-cause-duplicate-path-retrievements). I will try to release an update of the plugin in a couple of days.